# MacVim remember my old settings

Tags: vim, macvim

I have deleted my old .vimrc and .vim to configure vim from scratch. I have done it. But MacVim remembers my old settings, e.g. maps. Does it cache settings and plugins somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacVim has "Enable Quickstart" option in Preferences/Advanced and it caches settings for quick start if it is enabled. You should uncheck it to reset.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution

Comment: It works, and `defaults delete org.vim.MacVim` too. But do not forget to remove your session files.

Answer (score 0):

Try ls -a in HOME and verify exists swp file. If exists, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that resetting MacVim preferences solves the problem

```
defaults delete org.vim.MacVim
```